# Site appears as mobile version on Kindle Fire

Tags: nopcommerce, kindle-fire

My site is using nopcommerce and the mobile version is just a styled up version of nop default, which framework is jQuery mobile.

The mobile version appears on all tablet/mobile devices however, on the Amazon Silk I want it to appear as my desktop version as opposed to the mobile/tablet version.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want the full version on all tablets?

Comment: user can choose if they want mobile or desktop, but the only way for you to control that would be user agent detection (look for "Silk" and force desktop view)

Comment: I've already attempted to the user agent detection, however for some reason that didn't work.